# How to use psycopg2 to retrieve a certain key's value from a postgres table which has key-value pairs

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm new to `python`, trying to use `psycopg2` to read `Postgres`.

I am reading data from a database table called deployment and trying to handle a value from a table with three fields id, Key and value.

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost",database=database, user=user, password=password)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT \"Value\" FROM deployment WHERE (\"Key\" = 'DUMPLOCATION')")
records = cur.fetchall()
print(json.dumps(records))
[["newdrive"]]
```

I want this to be just "newdrive" so that, I can do a string comparison in the next line to check if it's "newdrive" or not

I tried json.loads on the json.dumps output, didn't work.

```
>>> a=json.loads(json.dumps(records))
>>> print(a)
[['newdrive']]

I also tried to print just the records without json.dump
>>> print(records)
[('newdrive',)]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of `fetchall()` is a sequence of tuples. You can loop over the sequence and print the first (index 0) element of each tuple:

```py
cur.execute("SELECT \"Value\" FROM deployment WHERE (\"Key\" = 'DUMPLOCATION')")
records = cur.fetchall()
for record in records:
    print(record[0])
```

Or simpler, if you are sure the query returns no more than one row, use `fetchone()` which gives a single tuple representing returned row, e.g.:

```py
cur.execute("SELECT \"Value\" FROM deployment WHERE (\"Key\" = 'DUMPLOCATION')")
row = cur.fetchone()
if row: # check whether the query returned a row
    print(row[0])
```