# Postgres check variable

Tags: python, postgresql

```
import psycopg2


try:
   connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                                  password="postgres",
                                  host="127.0.0.1",
                                  port="5432",
                                  database="adress")
   cursor = connection.cursor() 
   postgreSQL_select_Query = "select * from ip" 

   cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
   rules = cursor.fetchall()
   if rules=='1.1.1.1':
       print('OK')
   else:
       print('WRONG')
finally:
    if(connection):
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
```

I have created a database "address" with one table "ip" which contains a few values including "1.1.1.1".

When I execute the code shown above it returns "WRONG" value. How to fix that?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why do you think `fetchall()` can return anything that is comparable to a single string (or any single value from any one row)? Doesn't the name alone indicate that's not logical? But then I searched quickly for you, and immediately found that, indeed, it "fetches all rows in the result set and returns a list of tuples" - [link](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/query/). You need to know what types things return and work with them accordingly, not just write-and-hope.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use psycopg2 to retrieve a certain key's value from a postgres table which has key-value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55367647/how-to-use-psycopg2-to-retrieve-a-certain-keys-value-from-a-postgres-table-whic)

Comment: What host language is this? Add the tag.

Comment: @underscore_d  I am afraid it doesn't. What I am trying to do is check if my database contains a specific value (1.1.1.1 in my example) and if it does, it returns value "OK". I don't need to print this value (1.1.1.1) however.

Comment: @Mateusz The core of the problem is the same, that your result is a list of tuples and hence cannot just be compared to a string or any other single value. Figure out how to decompose the list/tuples to identify the row(s) and value(s) you want; it will not be that difficult at all.

Comment: Why don't you ask your database to search for a specific ip address? That's much faster and returns a single record instead of an unknown number of records. Could be millions...